# Simple Assembly Language task

Tags: assembly, marie

I'm reading the book: "The Essential of Computer Organization and Architecture, Linda Null and Julia Lobur". On chapter 4 page 172 it is a example how the assembly language work with instruction but I cannot understand it. I cannot understand because there is not a good explanation for the number on the image.

Here is the image: http://postimg.org/image/6imlsa3t9/

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Without further context there is no way to tell what the “similar procedure” from the excerpt or “the number” in your question are.

Comment: Your image host is cutting off so much of the page that I can't see what the book author is trying to convey.  Can you find a host who will let you display the full scan of the page ? I really can't see what that author is trying to convey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chapter deals with the MARIE Assembler and its instructions. Look at the program in table 4.3. Assembly syntax:

```
Load 104
Add 105
Store 106
Halt
0023
FFE9
0000
```

and the opcodes in hexadecimal (7 16-bit values):

```
0x1104
0x3105
0x2106
0x7000
0x0023
0xFFE9
0x0000
```

The question is: how to translate assembly to opcodes.

1) We have an instruction `Load X` which is number 1. This is the first hexadecimal number in the term or the first 4 bits of the 16-bit value. The rest (12 bits - 3 hexnumbers) contains the 'X' - in this case '104'. The whole term is `1104`.

2) For the second line we have to search anything appropriate with ADD in the instruction set and find `ADD X` (hexnumber 3). '3' & X => `3105`.

3) For the third line we connect `STORE X` (2) with '106' and get `2106`.

4) The fourth line stops the program with `HALT` (7). Nothing else, so the 16-bit-value is 7000. After the HALT there is no program left, but data.

HTH